# Is it possible to get tag-wise distribution of the votes that I have cast on questions?

Tags: support, tags, votes

So, I basically want to know what percent of my upvotes were cast on questions that are tagged with a particular tag say-X, and what percent of my downvotes are similarly cast for questions tagged with a particular tag.

Is it possible to generate such data?

Comment: As far as i know, there is no procedure to find it out.

Comment: You can add an answer if you want  expanding ur comment. @TheDestroyer

Comment: @Rickross There is already an answer saying the same. What is the need of a new one?

Answer (score 2):

<s>There is a way. In your profile's activity page, there is a section named "tags". The posts you have written and tag wise score is given in that section.</s>

**Update for revision 2:**

Only way to find out is finding through the votes section from our profile manually. There is no way to find the votes we have cast on others posts by tag wise.

As, the voting system is secretive, there is no way to find it through SEDE too.

The final answer to your question of finding out is "*No*. There is no way to find out the votes you cast on a particular tag".

Comment: I m asking about my votes on others' posts and you have given info about something else, so not an answer.

Comment: In first revision, it meant that you were asking about your tag wise score not the votes you have cast on. Be clear what you are asking.

Comment: No even then it was clear..now it is clearer. first revision had this - "what percent of **my upvotes were cast** on questions

Comment: "My upvotes" can mean the votes you got or the votes you cast. It is an ambiguous term. Now the question title is clear but not the body. For your recent question, there i no way to find your votes on particular tag on others posts.

Comment: @Rickross I edited the answer.